# Testing node.js with mocha and chai

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sequelize.js, chai, istanbul

I've been successfully testing my API endpoint built with node.js but still can't figure out how to test this kind of "non async" code.

```
/**
 * Database service
 */
// Dependencies
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(module.filename);
let db = {};

// Connection
let sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {logging: false});

// Models processing
fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(file =>
        (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) &&
        (file !== basename) &&
        (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
    .forEach(file => {
        /* uncovered */ const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
        /* uncovered */ db[model.name] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
    /* uncovered */ if (db[modelName].associate) {
    /* uncovered */     db[modelName].associate(db);
    /* uncovered */ }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

// Export everything
module.exports = db;
```

This is just a simple part of code which load all my Sequelize models (.js files) and create the associations.

While testing with istanbul, mocha and chai I can get full coverage over my API functions but can't get this code covered.

How should I test this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test something using the fs, IMHO you should use dependency injection in your module. This will aloow you to mock the fs:

```js
/**
 * Database service
 */
// Dependencies

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

makeDb = (fs, path) => {
        let db = {}
        const basename = path.basename(module.filename);
        // Connection
        let sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { logging: false });

        // Models processing
        fs
            .readdirSync(__dirname)
            .filter(file =>
                (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) &&
                (file !== basename) &&
                (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
            .forEach(file => {
                /* uncovered */
                const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
                /* uncovered */
                db[model.name] = model;
            });

        Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
            /* uncovered */
            if (db[modelName].associate) {
                /* uncovered */
                db[modelName].associate(db);
                /* uncovered */
            }
        });

        db.sequelize = sequelize;
        db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
        return db
    }
    // Export everything
module.exports = makeDb;
```

Then you use your module like this:

```js
//app.js
const fs = require('fs')
const makeDb = require("./db")
const db = makeDb(fs, path)
    /*
     * DO SOME STUFF
     */

//db.test.js
const fakeFs = require('mock-fs')
const makeDb = require("./db")
const testDb = makeDb(fakeFs, path)
```

This allows you to pass a fake FS to do your tests with mocka.

Mock-fs : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-fs